# Create #temp using SELECT INTO with desired data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For this simple statement:

`Select NULL as Col 
 INTO #temp`

The default datatype for NULL column is `int`, if I want to avoid creating `#` tables ahead and not using table variables, is there any way to default the NULL column as `varchar` when using `SELECT INTO` clause?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the point of what you are trying to do? can you elaborate on what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: that is just an example, the real case is the `union all` throw the error because it was trying to combining two different type columns

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just `CAST` it.

```
Select CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) as Col 
INTO #temp
```

There's no way of doing this as an implicit default for bare `NULL`s.

Comment: Thank you! :):):)

Answer (score 4):

The answers provided should suffice. I do this a lot; here's a few SELECT INTO techniques that I have found helpful (note my inline comments):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table #t1;
select 
  someid   = identity(int,1,1),          -- add an identity column 
  someTxt1 = cast('xxx' as varchar(10)), -- set the datatype
  someTxt2 = isnull(cast(555 as int), 0) -- set the column as not nullable
into #sometable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use convert as below:

```
select convert(varchar(10), null) as col into #temp
```

in place of 10 you can use your required size